# Vector calculus expression formatting

Tags: vector-calculus

I have the following example vector calculus code

```
gg := g[x, y, z];
gg[x_, y_, z_] := g[x, y, z];
Format[g[x, y, z]] = g;

f = Grad[x*gg, {x, y, z}];   
f // MatrixForm // pdConv
```

which produces the output
$$  
\displaystyle{\left( \begin{array}{c}  x \frac{\partial g }{\partial x}+g\\  x \frac{\partial g }{\partial y}\\  x \frac{\partial g }{\partial z}\\ \end{array} \right)}$$
But I would like the output format to be
$$
x \nabla g + 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 g  \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Is there a way to accomplish this?

The above of course is a simple example. I would like to have a code that finds the gradient terms and extracts them.

I'm using the [pdConv function](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/)

Comment: Del is undefined: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Del.html I would say define del and then expand it?

Comment: @CATrevillian the hard part is recognizing when the partials in a 3D vector (ie a list) can be combined after performing a calculation

Comment: You could possibly define your own simplification rule? I will visit this later today and provide the reference if I can find it.

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you!